# Ruby on Rails time match database start and end times

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, time

I've been banging my head at this one:

I have a table with columns `start_time` an `end_time` as well as `start_date` and `end_date`, and I have a `Time` object called `test_time`. I need to be able to match these values in a sql query. ie.

> Reservation.find :all, :conditions =>
>   ["'start_time' <= ? AND 'end_time' >=
>   ?", test_time, test_time]

Assuming we are only looking at Time and not Date, how can I determine whether or not `test_time` is within the range of time beginning at `start_time` and ending at `end_time`. In other words, 11:30am is between 11:15am and 11:45am. I've tried SQL BETWEEN clause, but was unsuccessful.

Comment: How is the time stored? I mean what format? Also may i ask, the need for the time column when the date field can take care of both.

Comment: I realized that the Time field is not necessary, so I will change that. The time is stored in SQLLite3 as type Time.

Answer (score 0):

you may be intereted in installing the ar-extensions plugin.  It provides an easy syntax to handle these types of queries.  I use it to find if a given latitude/longitude position is within a certain radius:

[ar-extensions](http://github.com/zdennis/ar-extensions)

Comment: I took a look at it, but I would prefer to not have to alter the core of Rails (I think that is what your suggestion does), and the documentation for that extension leaves a lot to be desired. Is there a plugin-free way to accomplish the above?